# TicTacToe game validation issue of two ints on the same scanner line

Tags: java, arrays, validation, java.util.scanner, tic-tac-toe

My issue is I don't know how to read two ints from the same scanner line (separated by spaces) and validate that they are both ints, and if not then print the appropriate error message and re prompt. It's some how printing the error message twice when I enter two non-ints as input

```
/**
 * Gets the position from the user of where the next move should be         
 * made. The board is then updated with a valid move
 *
 * @return true if there is a winner and false if there is no winner
 * 
 */



public boolean getMove()
{


boolean invalid = true;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;

//keeps asking for a position until the user enters a valid one
while (invalid)
{

    row = -1;
    column = -1;

    System.out.println("Which row, column would you like to move to? Enter two numbers between 0-2 separated by a space to indicate position in (x,y).");

    if (keyboard.hasNextInt())
    {

        row = keyboard.nextInt();

        if (keyboard.hasNextInt())
        {

            column = keyboard.nextInt();

        }
    } else
    {

        keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\nBoth inputs must be integers between 0 and 2.\n");

    }
    //check that the position is within bounds
    if (row >= 0 && row <= 2 && column >= 0 && column <= 2)
    {

        //check that the position is not already occupied
        if (board[row][column] != ' ')
        {
            System.out.println("That position is already taken");
        } else
        {
            invalid = false;
        }
    } else
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid position");
    }
}

//if it's currently X's turn then mark the space as char 'X' else 'O'
if (xTurn)
{
    board[row][column] = 'X';

} else
{
    board[row][column] = 'O';

}

//fill in the game board with the valid position
return winner(row, column);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can read it as a string, split by whitespace and get the value of each entry.